# Modify Auth-Type in post-proxy

Tags: freeradius

Good morning,

Is it possible to change the value of Auth-Type in the post-proxy section?

The remote proxy returns an Access-Accept packet and Auth-Type is initialized with the value Accept. I would like to follow with a local authentication in PAP.

Thanks for your answers.